# scipy basinhopping with callback: stop the algorithm when a condition is met

Tags: python, optimization, callback, scipy, minimization

my objective is, while using a `basinhopping` algorithm in order to find a global minimum, to stop the alogorithm whenever a condition is met after a minimum is found. by looking at the docs here (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.basinhopping.html), with special reference to this section, I deduced what I needed was the correct `callback`:

***callback :*** callable, callback(x, f, accept), optional
A callback function which will be called for all minimum found. x and f are the coordinates and function value of the trial minima, and accept is whether or not that minima was accepted. This can be used, for example, to save the lowest N minima found. Also, callback can be used to specify a user defined stop criterion by optionally returning True to stop the basinhopping routine.

therefore I thought that, by doing something like this:

```
def callback_on_optimization_indicator(x, f, accepted, threshold=2):

    if f > threshold:
        print(x, f, accepted, threshold)
        return f
    else:
        return False
```

and `callback=callback_on_optimization_indicator` should work. and effectively it does stop the `basinhopping` algorithm when the *"true"* part is met. problem is that, albeit the variables inside `callback_on_optimization_indicator` are the correct ones, when the optimization finishes and I examine the optimziation object, I get different values (both x0 and f). I have no idea why though.

Meaning with data:

```
(callback) x0  = [some data]
(callback) f = 2.60688517662
```

whereas in the optimziation object:

```
opt_obj.x = [different data]
opt_obj.fun = 1.6630711010135293
```

am i using the callback function incorrectly?

I would say so but I have yet to understand how to make it so that I get in the optimization object the first x0 that meets the condition in the `callback` (after a minimum is found)

Comment: the variables you get are the ones passed in when the callback is executed... now to get around this issue sometimes you can use something like a closure

Comment: closure? I am sorry I am unfamiliar with the term

Comment: this is my very simple version of explanation: when you define a function within the scope of another function, variable declarations in the outer function are available (‘closed over’) to the inner function .. google has lots of info , most of it confusing

Comment: @Asher11: Using [the example code in the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.basinhopping.html), I am not able to reproduce the problem. Can you provide a runnable example?

Comment: sorry, I have no idea why but by using def callback_on_optimization_indicator(x, f, accepted, threshold=2):

    if f > threshold:
        print(x, f, accepted, threshold)
        return True
    else:
        return False
I solved. I don't konw why because it's the first thing I tried (and at the time I was unseccssful) and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

The callback shows the x0 value before stopping.

opt_obj records the minimum up to that point (which is below the threshold of 2).